# Display arrow head with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display an arrow head next to my content DIV.

Its should be something similar to this -

[image]

My problem is when I adding contents to DIV, I can not keep the arrow head vertically center of the content DIV.

This is my HTML and CSS

```
<div id="mybox">
  <p></p>
</div>


#mybox {
    width:200px;   
    min-height:100px;
    background-color:green;
    position:relative;
}

#mybox:after {
    content:"";
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 20px solid #f00;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    right: -20px;
    top: 20px; 
}
```

Can anybody tell me how can I fix this problem?

[CSSDESK](http://cssdesk.com/9yCxc)

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the height of the arrow is known, you can just use a `top` value of `50%` and then a negative `margin-top` to displace the arrow's height:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/QEgxM/) - works for dynamic content now.

```
#mybox:after {
    content:"";
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 20px solid #f00;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    right: -20px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Alternatively, if the arrow's height isn't known, you could use the following instead:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/JGwW6/)

```
#mybox:after {
    /* Other properties.. */
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

Comment: I tried with `top:50%` before asking it here, but I couldn't get it to work. Anyway this is awesome solution. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/9k9Gu/

use

```
top:50%;
margin:-20px 0 0 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Display arrowhead before div is done using two-way either you can create two div or you can user `:before` or `:after` with div

take this example

```css
.arrow-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #f3f300;
  margin-left: 60px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
}

.big-reward {
  background-color: #faf300;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 0;
  color: #e21111;
}
```

```html
<div>
  $452
</div>
<div class="arrow-up"></div>
<div class="big-reward" id="mybox"><span><strong>Big Reward!</strong> Here is a sample text.</span></div>
```

Hey, also check this [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/W3CodeSchool/Ljwuxvan/)

Reference : [W3CodeSchool.com](http://w3codeschool.com/question/display-arrow-head-with-css/)